# ACPI Errors cannot be hidden

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, acpi

after the installation of 22.04 (kernel 6.2.0-33-generic) on a new PC (MB: Asus TUF GAMING B760M-PLUS, CPU: i5-13600k, GPU: Nvidia RTX 3060) I get quite a long list of ACPI Errors. They don't seem to be harmful, so I just wanna hide them. What can be found on the forum is the use of another level of logging, i.e. adding `loglevel=3` to the grub config file`/etc/default/grub` (of course with `sudo update-grub`). This does not silence the errors in my case, moreover higher loglevels (up to 0) do not hide the issue. I also tried adding `acpi=off` (system does not boot), `pci=noacpi`,  `acpi=force` -- so more or less everything that one can find in the forum.

Of course the BIOS was updated to the latest version, Secure Boot is off.

In principle I can live with these errors warnings, but I am still curious why the solution that is being repeated from thread to thread does not work in my case. Any idea or suggestion?

The output of `dmesg | grep -i "acpi"`:

```
[    3.560834] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.560849] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.560875] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.561047] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.561058] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.561080] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.561248] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.561259] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.561281] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.561448] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.561459] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.561480] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.561648] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.561659] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.561680] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.561847] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.561857] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.561879] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.562046] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.562057] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.562078] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.562251] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.562262] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.562279] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.562407] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.562418] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.562436] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.562564] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.562574] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.562592] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.562721] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.562731] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.562749] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.562877] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.562887] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.562905] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.563033] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.563043] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.563061] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.563189] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.563199] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.563217] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
[    3.563346] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsfield-184)
[    3.563356] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20221020/dswload2-477)
[    3.563374] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20221020/psparse-529)
```

Comment: wrong log level. or wrong usage. please add the actual line

Comment: @Rinzwind GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3"

Comment: it HAS to be after quiet (it is part of the quiet settings) Oh and add it to the q,,,, comments get deleted :) and you need 2 or lower

Comment: ok. I tried with other kernels: older one 6.2.0-26.26 and newer ones like 6.3.x and 6.4.x. The ACPI errors disappeared, but instead I got:
`usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71`
`usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71`
`usb usb3-port1:unable to enumerate USB device`

and apparently GPU has fallen apart and inactive

Answer (score 3):

This will:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet loglevel=2 splash"
```

(so does 0 and 1) and `fsck.mode=skip` will also nuke showing the fschk "clean" line and the "press control-c ..." line that does the filesystemcheck. In case you want a 100% clean boot.

`loglevel=` needs to be behind `quiet` with a space in front of it and will only suppress the messages on screen. These will still be on disk in the boot.log / `dmesg`

`loglevel` is a number from 0 (from bad) to 7 (to debugging) and mean `emerg`, `alert`, `crit`, `error`, `warn`, `notice`, `info`, `debug`. 3 means show "error" and worse.

Comment: I tried to put it behind quiet: in such a way GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=3 splash"

Comment: I will try it out

Comment: mine works ;=) I've been using that  since kernel 5.19 :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware about loglevels, i will give it a try -- to what you suggested

Comment: no, it is not working. These parameters appear in the grub when E is pressed. To mention, fsck.mode=skip seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the loglevel in Ubuntu (at least in 22.04) is managed by `/etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf`, which has a higher priority than the corresponding kernel parameters that seem to be ignored.

the line in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf` should be modified as follows to get the `loglevel=3` :

```
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 7
```