# ACPI BIOS Error-MSFT0101

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, acpi, grub-efi

I have Ubuntu and Windows on my laptop. I have two problems.

1. There is no dual boot to switch between the two operating systems.
2. I get a bunch of ACPI Bios errors that I don't know how to fix.

[image]

Comment: Forget about the ACPI notices. Those are not for us. There have been a lot of topics about this. There IS a method to suppress them. 1 of them that I answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487198/acpi-errors-cannot-be-hidden

Comment: Regarding the dual boot: the one tool to use here is "boot repair". https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/  It will gather data on all installs and recreate a boot based on the EFI systems it finds. Mind that if you erased Windows when installing Ubuntu this will not work. So please check with fdisk or gparted Windows is still there