ACPI erroor during boot
I encountered an error during system boot related to ACPI BIOS Error. Specifically, I'm getting the following error messages: [ 3.332391] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330) [ 3.332437] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
I'm using a Dell 7560 laptop with an Intel Core i9-11950K processor. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.19.17, and I've also tried kernel 6.5.0.28, but the same errors persist. I've tried researching this issue but haven't been able to find a solution. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem or provide guidance on how to resolve it? I would appreciate any assistance or advice.

Those are not for us but for kernel developers. We ALL have those. If you want to suppress them you can. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487198/acpi-errors-cannot-be-hidden has a method to suppress them some info here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot/1333162#1333162  and most are closed against that topic.

I have just written to Dell technical support, informing them of the issue. We will see what they will do about it. The only problem I have because of this is the issue of entering hibernation with newer kernels.

They will do nothing as it will be beyond them: this is a bug in the BIOS so AMI is the one that needs to fix this.  "The only problem I have because of this is the issue of entering hibernation with newer kernels." That might be unrelated. I have these notices too and both suspend and hibernation work for me (we ALL have these notices)

Maybe it's not related.  When initiating hibernation, the system successfully backs up to the swap space, and the screen powers off as expected. However, the laptop fails to power down completely—the power button remains illuminated, and the laptop begins to warm up significantly. If left in this state, it becomes excessively hot. Consequently, I am required to perform a hard reset by holding the power button until the device fully shuts down. Upon reboot, the system resumes from the swap memory seamlessly and operates without further issues.
